# lat_long = lat.text.strip('() ').split(',') :AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, distance, latitude-longitude

Need to find distance between 2 latitude and longitude. The Chrome is being controlled by the driver, then the latitude and longitudes are added to the suitable locations and the it also shows the distance value in the textbox, but it is not able to retrive that generated string of number.Here's the code.Kindly Help.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import csv
import time

with open('C:/Users/Nisarg.Bhatt/Documents/lats and 
longs/Lat_long_cleaned/retail_first.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f.read().splitlines(), delimiter = ',')
    data = [row for row in reader]

filename='C:/Users/Nisarg.Bhatt/Documents/lats and 
longs/Lat_long_cleaned/retail_first'    
option= webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument("-incognito")

path= "Y:/AppData/Local/chromedriver"
browser= webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path)

url="https://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/haversine/"
browser.get(url)

print(browser.title)

crash = 1
results = []
new=[]
skipped = []
for i,row in enumerate(data[1:]):
    print (i)
    search = browser.find_element_by_name('lat1')
    search_term = data[i+1][5]

    search_1=browser.find_element_by_name("lon1")
    search_term_1= data[i+1][6]

    search_2 = browser.find_element_by_name('lat2')
    search_term_2 = data[i+2][5]

    search_3 = browser.find_element_by_name('lon2')
    search_term_3 = data[i+2][6]


    search.clear()
    search_1.clear()
    search_2.clear()
    search_3.clear()

    try:
        search.send_keys(search_term)
        search_1.send_keys(search_term_1)
        search_2.send_keys(search_term_2)
        search_3.send_keys(search_term_3)

    except:
        print ('Skiped %s' %search_term)
        print (row)
        skipped.append(row)
        continue

    search.submit()
    time.sleep(1)

    try:
        lat = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/form/p[4]/input[2]")
    except:
        alert = browser.switch_to_alert()
        alert.accept()
        browser.switch_to_default_content()
        print ('Couldnt find %s' %search_term)
        print (row)
        skipped.append(row)
        continue

lat_long = lat.text.strip('() ').split(',')
lat_long_clean = [float(n) for n in lat]

try:
    browser.refresh()
except:
    with open(filename + 'recovered' + '%i' %crash + '.csv' , "wb") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(results)
        crash +=1

print (lat_long_clean)
r = row
r.extend(lat_long_clean)
r.insert(0, i)
print (r)
results.append(r)

with open(filename + ".csv", "a") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(r)

with open(filename + "comp.csv" , "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(results)
```

Comment: print (lat_long_clean)
r = row
r.extend(lat_long_clean)
r.insert(0, i)
print (r)
results.append(r)

with open(filename + ".csv", "a") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(r)

Comment: This part of the code is written in the except area of try and except and "NOT" seperately, Kindly note that

Comment: Try `find_element_by_xpath` instead of `find_elements_by_xpath`

Comment: TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not iterable, It gives this error if find_elements_by_path is used instead of elements